# Android adb error (error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Invalid argument)

Tags: android, adb

Help, im getting the following though ive already reinstalled/restarted the adb

xx@x-PC /d/asdk/platform-tools
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Invalid argument

Comment: did you try `adb kill-server; adb start-server` ?

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: You can see this issue for help. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219085

Answer (score 2):

On OS X I fixed it by killing the adb process and then starting the server:

```
$ killall adb
$ adb start-server
```